# Delphi XE6 Grid Index Out of Range Error with TValueListEditor with docolumnTitles DisplayOption set to False and one row only

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Create a form and place a `TValueListEditor`. Set the `doColumnTitles` display option to False. Try and delete the first row. You will get a `'Grid Index out of Bounds'` error. It is an ugly pig and so I am here to ask if using a try except block is the only way to deal with it?

Background:

Row is inherited from `TCustomGrid` via `TCustomDrawGrid` (Line 493 VCL.grids.pas) The property getter is private variable `FCurrent.Y`, the type of which is a value/field from a two value record. I cannot find where the `FCurrent` value is set by default (so it integer defaults to 0). It is not clear what values exist if the `TValueListEditor` has only one row and/or if there are no rows selected.

In any case, I get a Grid Index Out of Range Error - presumably raised from the `TCustomGrid` - but only if there is only one row and/or I attempt a delete on the first row in the `TValueListEditor` with `doColumnTitles := false`. Delete on other rows is fine. Regardless of whether this is a bug or not it seems somewhat stupid and inconsistent.

Is there a reason why the `TValueList` Editor constructor has inherited `RowCount := 2;`?

The error is thrown by `TValueListEditor.DeleteRow` according to:

```
  try
if (Strings.Count = 0) or
   (ARow < 1) or (ARow > RowCount - FixedRows) then
  {$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
  raise EInvalidGridOperation.CreateRes(SIndexOutOfRange);
  {$ELSE}
  raise EInvalidGridOperation.CreateRes(@SIndexOutOfRange);
  {$ENDIF}

Strings.Delete(ARow - FixedRows);
  finally
    FDeleting := False;
  end;
```

(See VCL.Valedit.pas at 804)

Is it a problem that there is an exception `if (ARow < 1)`?

Otherwise, perhaps it is that `FixedRows` is set in the constructor of the `TCustomGrid`:

```
constructor TCustomGrid.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
```

const
  GridStyle = [csCaptureMouse, csOpaque, csDoubleClicks,

```
                csNeedsBorderPaint, csPannable, csGestures];
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  if NewStyleControls then
    ControlStyle := GridStyle
  else
    ControlStyle := GridStyle + [csFramed];
  FCanEditModify := True;
  FColCount := 5;
  FRowCount := 5;
  FFixedCols := 1;
  FFixedRows := 1;
```

...

and the comments in the header of VCL.grids.pas say `"FixedRows The number of non-scrolling rows. This value must be at least one below RowCount."` (Line 138).

Methinks that there ends up being a problem with these values when the titles row is removed from the `TValueListEditor`

Anyway. My question is just - Does this require the use of an exception handler - or is there a more elegant way of un-kludging it?

Here is some basic no seatbelts code:

```
unit vleDebug;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.ValEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    vleWhoCaresNerd: TValueListEditor;
    Button1: TButton;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin    
      vleWhoCaresNerd.DeleteRow(vleWhoCaresNerd.Row);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
     vGUID: TGUID;
    begin
      vleWhoCaresNerd.InsertRow('id', GUIDToString(vGUID), True);
    end;

    end.
```

Here's the .dfm:

```
 object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = ':P'
  ClientHeight = 568
  ClientWidth = 633
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -13
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 120
  TextHeight = 16
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 295
    Top = 162
    Width = 242
    Height = 16
    Caption = 'Select and delete the first row if you dare.'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 63
    Top = 190
    Width = 393
    Height = 16
    Caption = 
      'Delete other rows if you like. Make some with  the  Add GUID But' +
      'ton.'
  end
  object vleWhoCaresNerd: TValueListEditor
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 617
    Height = 145
    DisplayOptions = [doAutoColResize, doKeyColFixed]
    Strings.Strings = (
      'jsonrpc=2.0')
    TabOrder = 0
    ColWidths = (
      150
      461)
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 159
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Add GUID'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object BitBtn1: TBitBtn
    Left = 550
    Top = 159
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'bbDelete'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = BitBtn1Click
  end
end
```

Comment: I have a feeling that grids don't like to be empty and I recall adding code to my grid to work around that

Comment: Yes. I see that this grid doesn't like to be empty. I was just checking that such a kludge is necessary. Bummer David.

Comment: I am also thinking that the kludge should be built into the TValueListEditor so we dumbass app developers don't have to deal with it.

Comment: Yes, I can see in my own grid, code to work around this issue. I guess you'll need to do likewise.